# Immediate up-voting of answer

Tags: discussion, upvotes

The answer in question I have deleted, a user pointed out to me that I did not understand the question properly and upon further inspection they were correct.

One thing I can't seem to shake is the fact that the answer was upvoted almost instantaneously, it would have been impossible for someone to read it and test that if it's correct and upvote.

My first question to meta is, what causes this to happen, is it just
 someone who is up-vote happy or some sort of script.

I m very new here and I am just trying to understand how things work.
If this question has been asked or discussed and I failed to search the correct keywords, please point me in the right direction. I am very curious

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Tip #1: don't go too fast. One vote, whether up or down, is absolutely irrelevant. People vote how they please, which can be for any reason good or bad. Take note of multiple votes instead.

Comment: Some voters are trigger happy. Nothing to be done about it unless they are targetting a specific user.

Comment: @yivi ah I see, that makes sense, it just took me off-guard cause it was as I posted the answer

Comment: One possibility is that this person might have been in the process of writing an answer identical to the one you posted when they saw the "New Answer" popup. Instead of finishing their duplicate answer, they just upvoted yours. The fact that it turned out to be a wrong answer, just means that they made the same mistake as you. There's no evidence for this, but I've upvoted answers within seconds of posting for just this reason.

Comment: @divibisan that's something that I didn't think about as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had these occasionally and had the same doubts. Possible suggestions for how these votes come about:

- Some people actually *can* assess your post at a glance - especially if they know that they've got the grace period to revert their vote in, if necessary. If you already have a rough idea (or, for that matter, a very precise idea) of what the answer should look like, you can sometimes recognise a correct answer in a couple of seconds without reading every word.
- Some question askers may reflexively upvote every answer out of gratitude. (They shouldn't do this, but "shouldn't" and "don't" are different words.)
- Some people are trigger-happy and don't scrutinise answers carefully before voting. Agree with the first sentence of the answer? Upvote! Answer looks relevant and nicely formatted? Upvote! (In my view, you really shouldn't do this either.)
- Some human beings are crazy and do irrational things that you will never make sense of.

In this case, since you say yourself that your answer was wrong and missed the point of the question, it sounds like one of the latter three possibilities was at play.

While it isn't literally impossible, I would be inclined to dismiss the idea that *"some sort of script"* is responsible. Users have limited votes and there's little reason that anyone would write an upvoting script.

Comment: I read all of it and then clicked upvote. My vote is legit and not scripted.